# i got this error TypeError: Cannot read property ‘url’ of null

Tags: laravel, vue.js

the problem is when i am rendering the content, i need to call {{ post.image.url }} but i get this issue “Cannot read property ‘url’ of null”

this is my code:

```
data() {
            return {
                posts: null,
                avatar: null
            }
        }

axios.get('/ajax/posts/' + user)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.posts = response.data.posts;
                        this.avatar = response.data.avatar;
                        console.log(response.data.posts);
                    });
```

and my php code for retrieving information:

```
public function ajaxGetPosts($user)
    {
        $profile = User::findOrFail($user)->first();

        //dd($user->posts()->withCount('image')->get());
        $posts = $profile->posts()->with('image')->get();
        return response()->json([
            'posts' => $posts->toArray(),
            'avatar' => $profile->getAvatar()
        ]);
    }
```

and result in console.log is:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "user_id":1,
   "title":"Dolores voluptatem culpa dolor est.",
   "body":"Iste et ratione atque inventore. Quo ex ea repellat saepe est ad est dicta. Magni eum omnis dolor quam provident mollitia.",
   "created_at":"2020-03-22T16:04:47.000000Z",
   "updated_at":"2020-03-22T16:04:47.000000Z",
   "image":    {
          "id":1,
          "url":"https://loremflickr.com/600/800",
          "imageable_type":"App\\Post",
          "imageable_id":1,
          "created_at":"2020-03-22T16:57:14.000000Z",
          "updated_at":"2020-03-22T16:57:14.000000Z"
       }
}
```

Comment: In a relationship like this, `post.image` can return `null`. You need to check for it: `post.image ? post.image.url : 'placeholder` (or similar), or enforce the image with `$profile->posts()->has('image')->with('image')->get()`.

Comment: Try with an if => v-if="post". When the component loads you have a null data

Comment: thanks Marc, i just need to add v-if="post.image"

Answer (score 0):

The comments give you some idea to fix the issue. and here is why:

when the page/component loading, if you are using `data` to render the template, it will render the template with the init data you defined, that's `null` for `posts` in your code.

to fix this, either you put some default data for your `data` prop in your Vue component. like

```
data() {
            return {
                posts:[{image:{url: "../assets/logo.png"}}],

            }
        }
```

or using `if` or `?:` in the template.

I personally like my way, this way lets you know what's your data struct is. make your code clear and easy to debug.